# Why's my response being executed more than once with the correct data instead of just only once with useEffect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I know having an empty dependency `[]` executes `useEffect()` only once but when it does execute only once with an empty dependency `[]` - it logs an empty array in the console.

When it's not empty, it just continuously logs with no end in sight (with the correct data).  I'm not sure why it won't log it correctly just one time with the data I need to use.

What am I doing wrong?

Code below:

```
const [uploadsData, setUploadsData] = useState([]);

const getUploads = async () => {
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }

    await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/get-uploads', {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
            setUploadsData([resp.data]);
        }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    getUploads();
    // logs empty array in the console if dependency array is empty
    // logs correct data when dependency array isn't empty - i.e. [uploadsData]
    console.log(uploadsData);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are referring the `uploadsData` inside the `useEffect` hook's callback and in order to get correct console log, you should run that code in a separate `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUploads();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    // logs empty array in the console if dependency array is empty
    // logs correct data when dependency array isn't empty - i.e. [uploadsData]
    console.log(uploadsData);
}, [uploadsData]);
```

In this way, the `getUploads` function is called only once and it outputs correct `uploadData` to the browser console.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, Alan!  The only thing that's still kind of odd's is logging.  The very first `console.log()` that lives inside the `useEffect()` hook containing the comments is simply logging an empty array - followed by the `console.log(resp);` logging the response.  Then finally, logging the data correctly via the very first `console.log()` that lives inside the `useEffect()` hook containing the comments.  So three logs.  But the very first log is an empty array.  Is this normal and expected?

Comment: @sp92 yeah, exactly. If you don't add that dependency to the `useEffect` hook, it will be updated next re-render of the component and it outputs the previous `uploadsData`.

Comment: ok, I see.  Thanks again!  Just out of curiosity - is there a way to do this without use two `useEffect()` hooks?  Seems kinda insufficient.  Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong :).

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use `useEffect` hook to print that data as it's not related to the development and business logic. Just use that inside the component directly if you just want to see the `uploadsData` variable change. :)

Answer (score -1):

The first time it will print empty array since update state is async in React.

GIVEN that you add uploadsData to your dependency array.
WHEN your effect runs, it updates uploadsData
THEN the effect will be triggered again.

This will go on forever!

Comment: yeah, I got it now.  But how'd I make it so that it only logs once with the correct date as opposed running forever with the correct data?  When the dependency array's empty, it logs an empty array once.  When the dependency array's not empty, it logs continuously (with the correct data) infinitely.